# How to get json data on frontend controller in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, json

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use regular JSON response class:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

class Test extends Action
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
     */
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Dispatch request
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $result */
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $resultData = [
            'any_key' => 'Any data goes here',
            'success' => true,
            'time' => time(),
            'replace_button_message' => __('Your store has been already registered'),
        ];

        return $result->setData($resultData);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply @Siarhey Uchukhlebau  i am getting error with your code Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed

Comment: @Rahulocodewire try to clear your var/generation directory

Comment: @Rahulocodewire Could you add here a full error trace?

Comment: i am getting this error Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to Ocodewire\Parcelninja\Controller\Index\Index::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory, instance of Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory given, called in /var/www/html/magento/magento2/fybr/var/generation/Ocodewire/Parcelninja/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in /var/www/html/magento/magento2/fybr/app/code/Ocodewire/Parcelninja/Controller/Index/Index.php on line 19

Comment: @Rahulocodewire You should remove old generated files: `rm -rf var/generation/*` from the magento root directory.

Comment: @Rahulocodewire does it helped you?

Comment: thanks it work but how i get responce from api in this controller can you please tell me ?

Comment: api send data in my controller url can you please tell me how i get the responce data from api in my controller ?

Comment: @Rahulocodewire Could you ask a separate question and post the link here? To say something I should know more info - what you try to achieve and which method you are using? If your question is about a custom api here is [a good article written by Alan Kent](https://alankent.me/2015/07/24/creating-a-new-rest-web-service-in-magento-2/)

Comment: @Rahulocodewire If you wish to get just a request parameters you should use `$params = $this->_request->getParams()`

Comment: getting empty array ()

Comment: @Rahulocodewire This means that there are no parameters in this request. Please accept my answer if it was helpful for you and ask another question where you can specify all about your current problem. I'll try to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using following code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Controller\Controller\Index;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $jsonResult = ['data' => 'test'];

        $this->getResponse()->representJson(
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class)->jsonEncode($jsonResult)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx for reply can you please  post full controller

Comment: No problem, I've updated my answer.

Comment: thanks  its worked but i actually  i want get response from api when i print the request i get only empty array

Comment: api send data in my controller url can you please tell me how i get the responce data from api in my controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
$this->getResponse()->representJson($this->_objectManger->get(Your Path::class)->JsonEncode($jsonResult));
```